Why does java.util.Collection#parallelStream triple the runtime when using a single thread?
Why does the execution time of java.util.Collection#parallelStream not match the expectation?
The result of cost is about 30s, expect 10s.
    private void process(int i) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000); // 10s
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testPartition() {
        List<Integer> numbers = IntStream.range(1, 21).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        long cost = 0L;

        long jobStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        numbers.parallelStream().forEach(x -> {
            process(x);
        });

        cost += (System.currentTimeMillis() - jobStart);

        System.out.println("availableProcessors = " + Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        System.out.println("cost = " + cost);
    }

It seems runs process(x); 3 times. why is that?
@daniu is correct.

The ForkJoinPool in Java uses a default thread number that is equal to the number of available processors, as reported by the Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() method. This design is intended to efficiently utilize the available CPU resources for parallel processing tasks.

output:
availableProcessors = 8
cost = 30015


Probably beside the point, but what makes you say "using a single thread"? By default, parallelStream uses the default ForkJoinPool IIRC. Why are you declaring a long[] and then only use the first element to add up the time?

Are you expecting it to start up 20 different threads? Why do you assume that?

even better to include a [mre] in such questions... e.g. we do not know what Lists is (sure we can assume it)

Thanks to @daniu. parallelStream uses the default ForkJoinPool. The ForkJoinPool in Java uses a default thread number that is equal to the number of available processors.
availableProcessors = 8
then 20/8=3, that's why the cost is about 30s rather than 10s.

BTW you can change the number of threads by calling ForkJoinPool.commonPool().setParallelism(20) - this should result in a value near 10s for posted code

@user85421 – If you are using VirtualThreads, this is very likely. But with the hardware threads, I would say that depends on the OS and the hardware. From the Javadoc for Thread::sleep: "The thread does not lose ownership of any monitors." In some enviroments, this also means that it will not release the core. On my Unix box, it was close to 10, on my NXT, it was above 400 (ok, the Java implementation on the last is poor, at best).
